# Функция возвращает некорректное значение

Tags: javascript

Есть простая функция которая принимает значение обрабатывает его и возвращает

пример

```js
console.log(getMony(7506))

function getMony(a) {
  var b = a - 5000;
  b = b * 0, 0035

  return b;

}
```

Но функция возвращает 0. Почему ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Допущены синтаксические ошибки в теле функции:

```js
console.log(getMony(7506))

function getMony(a) {
  var b = a - 5000;
  b = b * 0.0035;

  return b;

}
```

разделителем целой и дробной части является точка и вконце строки не хватает точки с запятой

Answer (score 2):

Потому что надо писать `0.0035`, а не `0,0035`